# How to create delayed charges with Craft Commerce or use Stripe's stripe-php library directly

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I need to have delayed credit card charges for my client.  From
Stripe's end it looks fairly straightforward by creating a customer and
saving their information for a later charge.

https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later

But, it looks like Omnipay doesn't support Stripe's Customers.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862591/2177602

One solution might be to create my own payment gateway plugin for Craft commerce
that doesn't use Omnipay but it's implied that Omnipay is required according to
https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways#adding-additional-gateways.

It looks like I need to use Stripe's `stripe-php` library directly.  How
would I do that and integrate with Craft commerce?